# Kubernetes service does not have endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-service

I have a kubernetes service and defined as:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-exporter
  labels:
    type: prometheus-monitorable
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: myapp
    project: myproject
  ports:
    - name: prometheus-exporter
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5555
      targetPort: 5555
```

When I execute `kubectl get endpoints` I see endpoints is none.

I thought that service label does not match but when I run `kubectl get pods  --show-labels` I can see the pod has label myapp. So what is wrong and my service does not have any endpoint ?

Comment: Does it have both labels `app: myapp` and `project: myproject`?  Can you show the pod YAML's `metadata:` block?

Comment: I found out that it  does not have one of them. So I have removed it. Thanks a lot.